# How to solve linear equation using inversion method?

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not understand the inversion method to solve a pair of linear equations:

> 2x<sub>1</sub> + 4x<sub>2</sub> = 4
> 9x<sub>1</sub> + 3x<sub>2</sub> = 6

How to solve this? Please clarify steps.

Comment: Writing it as $Ax=b$ and solving it as $x=A^{-1}b$. Are you familiar with such linear algebra?

Comment: @EricS. i am new student but i can't understand my today's lecture. please help me to understand concepts of this Question related material .

Comment: @MAbidMajeed: should we guess what your today's lecture was about ? Provide more details, there isn't a single way to solve such a system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write in a matrix form $Ax=b$, i.e.
$$\pmatrix{2&4\\9&3}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}=\pmatrix{4\\6}$$
Using the following formula of inverse matrix
$$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}^{-1}=\frac{1}{a d-bc}\pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}$$
one get
$$x=\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}=A^{-1}b=\frac{1}{2\cdot3-9\cdot4}\pmatrix{3&-4\\-9&2}\pmatrix{4\\6} =\\
-\frac{1}{30}\pmatrix{3\cdot4-4\cdot6\\-9\cdot4+ 2\cdot6}=
-\frac{1}{30}\pmatrix{-12\\-24}=\frac{1}{5}\pmatrix{2\\4} $$

Alternatively one obtain an inverse using matrix ranking
$$\pmatrix{2&4&|&1&0\\9&3&|&0&1}\rightarrow_{swap}\\
\pmatrix{9&3&|&0&1\\2&4&|&1&0}\rightarrow_{\text{second row}\times 4.5}\\
\pmatrix{9&3&|&0&1\\9&18&|&4.5&0}\rightarrow_{row_2=row_2-row_1}\\
\pmatrix{9&3&|&0&1\\0&15&|&4.5&-1}\rightarrow_{row_1=row_1/9,row_1=row_1/15}\\
\pmatrix{1&1/3&|&0&1/9\\0&1&|&3/10&-1/15}\rightarrow_{row_1=row_1-row_2/3}\\
\pmatrix{1&0&|&-1/10&2/15\\0&1&|&3/10&-1/15}
$$
Thus
$$
A^{-1}=\pmatrix{-1/10&2/15\\3/10&-1/15}=\frac{1}{30}\pmatrix{-3&4\\9&-2}
$$

Comment: Please dear sir can you clarify me step taken to solve this Question please humble request ?

Comment: edited, please let me know if this is better now, otherwise please ask specific question so I know exactly how to help you.

Comment: How you take A inverse ?

Comment: this is well known formula, but if you don't know it I can develop it from scratch. Do you know matrix ranking?

Comment: I have fixed a little mistake, now this is the same answer as Jan's

Comment: tell me about matrix ranking !

Comment: see the example

Comment: Thankyou So much GOD BLESS YOU

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{cases}
2x_1+4x_2=4 \\
9x_1+3x_2=6
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2x_2 \\
9x_1+3x_2=6
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2x_2 \\
9(2-2x_2)+3x_2=6
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2x_2 \\
18-18x_2+3x_2=6
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2x_2 \\
18-15x_2=6
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2x_2 \\
-15x_2=6-18
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2x_2 \\
-15x_2=-12
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2x_2 \\
15x_2=12
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2x_2 \\
x_2=\frac{12}{15}
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2x_2 \\
x_2=\frac{4}{5}
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=2-2\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) \\
x_2=\frac{4}{5}
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=\frac{2}{5} \\
x_2=\frac{4}{5}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: your answer is different ...How can i accept yours or Michael Medvinsky Solution please tell me which method is more realible and exatly true ??

Comment: @MAbidMajeed I've checked my answer with Mathematica and it gave me the same!

Comment: Very Well you answer is too much correct but i had mention that i want to solve this by Inversion method  :) Thank you so much for this method it is also helpful for me